# How to write java script in nifi to decrypt jwt token using Apache NiFi. How to use ExecuteScript processor

Tags: javascript, apache-nifi

I am new to NiFi and JavaScript. I am trying to decrypt the jwt token using executecommand processor. But failing to do so. I have attached my code. Can you please help me on the same. the library we are using here is node-jose:

```js
flowFile = session.get();
if (flowFile != null) 
{
    var jweToken = flowFile.getAttribute('token')
    var contentAlg = 'A256CBC-HS512';
    const privKeyJwks = {"p:aaaaaabbbccccc,q:cddbcbvbvbmm"};
    async function decryptJWE(jweToken) {
        try {
                // Decrypt JWE w/ private key
                const privKey = await JWK.asKey(privKeyJwks);
        return (await JWE.createDecrypt(privKey).decrypt(jweToken)).plaintext.toString();
    
    flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, 'token', 'jweToken')
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
            }
}
}
```

the errors I am getting:

1. Failed to process session due to javax.script.ScriptException: :13:6 Expected ; but found function async function decryptJWE(jweToken)
   Failed to process session due to javax.script.ScriptException: :13: expected operand but found const

please help me. thank you.

Comment: so obvious error `Expected ;` - just add `;` at the end of line 13

Comment: @daggett, still getting the error its saying Expected an operand but found const
const privKeyJwks, and for async fuction as well. i am using ExecuteScript processor here

Comment: Your code currently is syntactically invalid. What do you mean by `{private_key object}`? If this is some kind of placeholder for the real data, could you stub just the data itself, preserving their structure?

Comment: @Cerberus, yes in that there is real time json object I have to use. Do you have solution to my problem?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can find, Apache NiFi uses [Nashorn](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/jdk.scripting.nashorn-summary.html) as its JavaScript (ECMAScript, to be exact) implementation. According to the docs, Nashorn supports only ECMAScript 5.1; however, you're using async functions, which are supported only in ECMAScript 2017 and later.

The only way to go is to rewrite your script without using async functions.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I don't know Javascript. this function is provided by other person. Have you ever worked on such requirement ? If so can please share the code with me?

Comment: You could ask another question (not about NiFi, but about ECMAScript 5.1 in general) with self-contained example (with definitions of `JWK.asKey` and `JWE.createDecrypt` and without `session` manipulations), so that someone more experienced comes in. I'll try to answer there too, just can't promise that this would be optimal.